# BeautifulSoup string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I get the price £500,000 out of this HTML?

```
<p class="price" id="price-detail">
<span class="price-modifier">From</span>
        £500,000
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.next_sibling` result of finding elements with a `price-modifier` class perhaps?

```
print unicode(soup.find(class_='price-modifier').next_sibling)
```

Comment: [x for x in soup.find(id='price-detail').stripped_strings][-1]....feels a bit hacky. Thought there should be a way of getting the value of the tag and ignoring the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a very elegant solution, but its an alternative to Martijn's suggestion:

```
p = soup('p',{'id':'price-detail'})[0]
modifier = p('span',{'class':'price-modifier'})[0].contents[0]
price = p.findAll(text=True)

if modifier in price:
    price.remove(modifier)

print ' '.join(x for x in price)
```